# Is JSON_SET with JSON_EXTRACT in MySQL atomic?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table that has a JSON field called 'counter'. 'counter' is an an array. I want to write a query that atomically increments a value in the array. Is the following query atomic?

`UPDATE table SET counter = JSON_SET(counter, '$[0]', JSON_EXTRACT(counter, '$[0]') + 1) WHERE id='xyz';`

Answer (score 1):

Effectively yes, because as your UPDATE statement examines the row, it becomes locked. Other sessions can't update it simultaneously.